# SOCK_RAW packets don't send with certain source address

Tags: c, sockets, ip

I'm working on a netcat like tool (mostly for self education). I'd like to send packets with IP and UDP headers I've constructed through a `SOCK_RAW` socket. I'm running the following code on a Debian VM to send the packet through the socket.

```
/* header must already have source IP, destination IP, and protocol number filled in */
int send_ip_packet(ipheader_t *header, char *buf, int numbytes)
{
    int sizeofpacket = sizeof(ipheader_t) + numbytes;
    if(sizeofpacket > MAX_PCKT_LEN)
    {
        printf("Cannot send ip packet of len %i. Too large. - FAIL\n", sizeofpacket);
        return -1;
    }

    /* open a raw socket */
    int sd;
    sd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, header->ip_p);
    if(sd < 0)
    {
        perror("socket()");
        printf("socket() call - FAIL\n");
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("socket() call - SUCCESS\n");
    }

    char packet[sizeofpacket];
    memset(packet, 0, sizeofpacket);

    /* set remaining ip header */
    header->ip_hl = 5; /* header length is 5 32-bit octets */
    header->ip_v = 4; /* IPv4 */
    header->ip_tos = 16; /* low delay */
    header->ip_len = sizeofpacket;
    header->ip_id = htons(54321); /* identifier used for fragmentation */
    header->ip_off = 0; /* fragmentation options */
    header->ip_ttl = 64; /* max num hops */
    header->ip_sum = csum((unsigned short*)packet, sizeofpacket);

    /* fill packet */
    memcpy(packet, (char*) header, sizeof(ipheader_t));
    memcpy(packet + sizeof(ipheader_t), (char*) buf, numbytes);

    /* setup socket addresses */
    struct sockaddr_in sin, din;
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    din.sin_family = AF_INET;
    memcpy(&sin.sin_addr.s_addr, &header->ip_src, sizeof(in_addr_t));
    memcpy(&din.sin_addr.s_addr, &header->ip_dst, sizeof(in_addr_t));

    /* send out the packet */
    int one = 1;
    int *val = &one;
    if(setsockopt(sd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, val, sizeof(one)))
    {
        perror("setsockopt()");
        printf("setsockopt() call - FAIL\n");
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("setsockopt() call - SUCCESS\n");
    }

    if(sendto(sd, packet, header->ip_len, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &sin, sizeof(sin)) < 0)
    {
        perror("sendto()");
        printf("sendto() call - FAIL\n");
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Message sent! - SUCCESS\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The code successfully sends a packet visible in wireshark as long as the source IP I supply is NOT that listed as my "true" IP when I run `ifconfig`. Can anyone tell me why this might be or how I might fix it (besides not using `SOCK_RAW`)? I would assume the OS is treating the packet specially, but why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sendto()` expects the destination address as 5th parameter.

From the variable naming given in the OP I strongly assume source address is passed in, which would perfectly explain the bahaviour described.